# French Unix Linux questions? Est-ce qu'il y a un site / lieu de questions Unix / Linux en francais?

Tags: discussion

- Is there a related (stack exchange) place where we can ask *NIX questions in french?
- If not, what would be an example of a relatively (in context) popular *NIX site that would accept french or multilingual questions?

Comment: As a workaround, feel free to use tools like google translate if writing the question/answer is too hard for you. Just include a note like "Sorry for the English, I am using Google translate" and I'm sure someone will edit the post so it's better. As for understanding answers, you could ask in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat). I'm sure someone will help you out. Il y a pas mal des gens qui parlent français ici.

Comment: You can try the `fr.comp.os.unix` usenet newsgroup. Mostly dead nowadays but you could try and revive it.

Comment: As @terdon stated, people like me spend most days editing questions that fall into your question here, and we answer a few as we go.  All we ask is that you don't think that we changed the intent of the question via the edit.  If that happens let us know via comments .

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, Stack Exchange has reneged on its [permission to create non-English sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52331/is-it-ok-to-have-non-english-question-and-answers-in-area-51/53004#53004). The rules are now that non-English sites:

- [must be about programming](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20987/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-stack-overflow-edition);
- must be in one of a small set of languages for which Stack Exchange is willing to hire a community manager.

The [official status of non-English non-programming sites](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20988/internationalization-state-of-the-stack-se-2-0-sites-edition) is “not yet” — and given how long we've waited, been told “yes” only to be told “no” after a proposal had gained momentum, I've given up hope. The official rule is that a site about programming must exist before Stack Exchange will even consider the possibility of a site about a different topic, and that hasn't happened yet.

The exception is sites about languages, e.g. [French Language](https://french.stackexchange.com/) accepts questions in French (about the French language, of course). But unfortunately those sites only have an interface in English.

So no, there won't be a Stack Exchange site about Unix in French any time soon. And be wary of promises from Stack Exchange, there's a long history of them going back on their promises.

---

Outside Stack Exchange, unfortunately, question-and-answer sites suck. There's Usenet, Reddit, the [Linuxfr forums](http://linuxfr.org/forums), etc. But they lack the tools and the community to be good at answering questions.

Comment: What would be the incentive for knowledgeable people to watch and answer? On the whole, French IT people aren't that bad at English. People who ask questions on French sites are mostly people who couldn't Google in English, so answering them is merely being a translating proxy and isn't very challenging.

Comment: @xenoid On the whole, French IT people aren't very good at English. (Obviously, the ones you see on English-speaking forums are better than average.) People who ask questions on English sites are mostly people who couldn't Google, so … how would a French site be different?

Answer (score 2):

You can see the list of Stack Exchange sites [here](http://stackexchange.com/sites), and the list of proposed sites [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com). As far as I know the only site to fork into multiple languages is Stack Overflow, and it only has [Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/), [Russian](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/), [Portugese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), and soon to be [Turkish](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/34945/stack-overflow-in-turkish); I don't see anything in French. You could try [proposing a new site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology), but it takes a while to get going.

Comment: Thank you.  Yes I should have mentioned I know the main list of sites but I was unaware of the StackOverflow forks.

Comment: I am curious to know what this moderator thinks (if he is so inclined) because of his extended background in both fields.  Is there a respectful way to bring it to his attention?  http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles?tab=profile

Comment: @BloodyEl That's a good thought. He's in [/dev/chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/dev-chat) right now, the general chat room for this site

Comment: no prejudice re: vote.  promise ;)